# Pandoc not converting inside custom environment

Tags: itemize, pandoc

I use custom enviroments to produce Theorems, Lemma, Propositions, etc in a LaTex file like this:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

When I use Markdown+pandoc I write:

```
\thm{A theorem.}
```

And I get the desire result.
But when I want to use a list inside it:

```
\thm{A theorem.

1. Item1
2. Item2 }
```

I get:

**1. Theorem 1.** A theorem.

1. Item1 2. Item2

Instead of:

**1. Theorem 1.** A theorem

1. Item1
2. Item2

I don't know how to fix this problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How would you like the output to look?

Comment: You should refer to this discussion: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3145 It is impossible to natively have pandoc parse markdown inside Latex environments, but you can use some tricks to have it to work.